# jtds driver fails to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 in ssl=require mode

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssl, java-6, jtds

I'm having an issue connecting to SQL Server 2008R2 using SSL.

- jtds driver 1.2.8
- jre 1.6.45
- sql server 10.50.2500

Connecting in plain text mode works fine:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server01:40033;databaseName=OperationsManagerDW
```

However connecting in encrypted mode with ssl require property fails:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server01:40033;databaseName=OperationsManagerDW;ssl=require
```

Notice ssl=require property in JDBC url above. 
Applying -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false setting has no effect.

```
ava.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:355)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:178)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at SCOMDbConnect.openConnection(SCOMDbConnect.java:347)
    at SCOMDbConnect.main(SCOMDbConnect.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.SocketFactories$TdsTlsSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactories.java:102)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.enableEncryption(SharedSocket.java:245)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.negotiateSSL(TdsCore.java:509)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:318)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.TdsTlsInputStream.primeBuffer(TdsTlsInputStream.java:109)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.ssl.TdsTlsInputStream.read(TdsTlsInputStream.java:78)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    ... 16 more
```

Has anyone similar problems and was able to fix it? I'm thinking of patching SQL server as outlined here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2653857/ but it's not clear it would help me.

UPDATE 1: jre 1.6.27 works ok in SSL mode.

Comment: How have you setup your truststore?

Comment: Certificate errors are supposed to be gracefully ignored, note that I'm using ssl=ignore and not ssl=authenticate which is going to throw a certificate error. Also, the exception above is raised before it gets to down certificate matters.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to jre 1.6.27 up patching JRE solved the issue.